# Error creating maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, maven, m2eclipse

I am trying to create a maven project in Eclipse(neon.1 version) on macOS Sierra, but whenever i create a project, no matter with what/which type of  archetype or configuration i choose, i always get these errors, which are shown in screenshot:

[image]

And the error in `pom.xml` is :

[image]

I have not been able to find any solution from anywhere till now, have been working on this issue from weeks.

Comment: Are you behind any proxy??

Comment: NO. @SachinSarawgi

Comment: Right Click Project->Maven->Update Project. Try it.

Comment: tried it many times.. still the same result @SachinSarawgi

Comment: In your xml `project` attribute `xsi:schemaLocation` replace `maven-4.0.0.xsd` with `maven-v4_0_0.xsd`.

Comment: Try this also - go to your user folder, inside it there's a ".m2" folder, open it and delete the folder "repository". Go to eclipse, clean your project, then right click->Maven->Update Project

Comment: you can do another process. use mvn over command line with task "eclipse" to setup the maven project. CLose your Project go to the directly of project and execute mvn eclipse:eclipse. Open the project after this. Also mention if are getting any errors in doing so

Comment: @Acewin this has not worked correctly for many years and it will just make a complete mess of his project.

Comment: Do you have a Java JDK installed (rather than just the JRE)?

Comment: not sure, but it has definitely helped me many times

Comment: I have both java JDK and JRE, when i create ant other java project, it get created successfully, only MAVEN given me this error when creating project. @SteveC

Comment: i tried what you said, but it didn't helped me, even if it would have worked, i always have to build the project that way, but i want to make from eclipse only. @Acewin

Comment: Install M2Eclipse https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/

Comment: could you build the project by invoking maven directly. You could try within eclipse - project > run > maven build. If you can build successfully I would suggest to resolve these issues as ignore in workspace and that should work for you

Comment: As @SachinSarawgi suggested, try Maven-> Update Project, but make sure to check the option "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite sure that you would have already tried, if not please remove the entire maven from your system ( generally `.m2` folder in windows) and create a new `workspace` in eclipse and do a fresh setup from scratch.

I do not remember the error I faced, but after struggling for many hours this worked for me.

**If you have installed maven manually also, as I mentioned, below will be the path :**

In simple, when you build a Maven project, all dependency files will be stored in your Maven local repository. 
By default, Maven local repository is default to `.m2` folder :

```
Unix/Mac OS X – ~/.m2
Windows – C:\Documents and Settings\{your-username}\.m2
```

Comment: i have already tried this and it worked after doing this same thing 100th time.. but still your answer is relevant.. it worked the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the integrated maven from eclipse and setup the installed maven from eclipse
Preferences/user settings

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail on removing the integrated maven and setting up the installed maven?

Comment: Go To Windows->Prefrences-Maven->Installations and edit the installation
You need to delete the integrated one and add the one that is downloaded separately, for that you need to browse the maven installation directory.